# How to create a new list of lists from a list of lists in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I've a field made of list of lists like this:

```
let list1 = ["a", "abcdefgh", "abc"]
```

I want to get a new field 5x5 such that there could be more then 5 lines or columns, but no less. It must be produced from the previous one by addition spaces ' ' or keeping them as they are, if there are more then 5 symbols. For additional lines no spaces needed. For example:

```
list2 = ["a    ", "abcdefgh", "abc  ", "     ", "     "]
```

or:

```
let list1 = ["a", "abcdefgh", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
list2 = ["a    ", "abcdefgh", "c    ", "d    ", "e    ", "f"]
```

I thought about map, replicate, and length, but I'm a little bit confused.
If it's possible, don't use libs (or use Data.Map only). Thank you

Comment: Exactly *what* did you try?

Comment: I made sth. like this:
(map (++ (replicate 5 ' ')) linesOfFiles) ++ (replicate (5- length linesOfFiles) (replicate 5' '))
But that's not what I want

Comment: Your map will each time add five spaces to each line. You should determine the length of the string, and append accordingly...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, I know, but I don't know how I can determine the length of the string inside the map function

Comment: you work with a lambda expression: `map (\x -> ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine the length of the strings. You can do this for example with a *lambda expression*, so then the mapping looks like:

```
func :: [String] -> [String]
func mylines = map (\x -> … ) linesOfFiles ++ replicate (5-length mylines) (replicate 5' ')
```

where `x` is thus string that will be mapped, and `…` is an expression to what that value is mapped. I leave filling in `…` as an exercise.

Usually it is better *not* to work with `length`: `length` takes linear time, and for infinite lists, this will even get the program into an infinite loop.

You can work with recursion to perform padding, something like:

```
padding :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
padding 0 _ xs = …
padding n x [] = …
padding n x (x:xs) = …
```

Comment: Thank you, I already understood this after your first comment. I'm just trying to do it now

Comment: Thanks again, I've not so much pracrice in lambda usage.I know about the linear time, but I get the list form the input file, so it doesn't take so much time.
I made: (map (\x -> (x ++ (replicate (5 - (length x)) ' '))) linesOfFiles) ++ (replicate (5- length linesOfFiles) (replicate 5' '))

Comment: @TheWorstHaskellProger: Instead of computing the *number* of spaces, one way to avoid `length` is to think of the problem as: 1. pad the input with spaces in both directions, *then* 2. trim it to the desired size with `take`. Look at the result of `take 5 ("abc" ++ repeat ' ')`, and consider how you could use this pattern in your code. Also, notice how `take 5 (x ++ repeat ' ')` is different from `x ++ replicate (5 - length x) ' '` when `length x` is greater than 5, as in `"abcdefg"`. Your question and your sample input/output are a little unclear about which of these results you want.

Comment: @JonPurdy Sorry, I made a mistake when I wrote "there could be more then 5 lines or columns, but no more" I should have written "no less". So you see, `replicate (length (-10)) ' '` will not change my line, but `take const` will cut my lines. I'll correct the error right now. Thank you for the answer